# Python function: return x < y

Tags: python, function

What does it mean if you in your return statement in a function in Python say

```
return x < y
```

Will it only return x if x < y? And in that case what would it return if x > y?

Comment: `x < y` is a Boolean. That is what is returned.

Comment: It will return `True` or `False` depending on values of x and y

Comment: it will either return `True` if the condition is true or `False` otherwise.

Comment: You can check it yourself.

Comment: It would have been *easier* to check it yourself (`def f(x,y): return x < y`. Plug in a few values) than it was to write this question. Get in the habit of experimenting in Python. The shell lends itself to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the boolean value of the expression `x < y`, if `x = 1` and `y = 2` it returns `True`.

Answer (score 0):

**When in doubt,  try it out.** Ohe of the great advantages of interpreted languages is how easy this is:

```
>>> def f(x,y):
...   return x < y
... 
>>> f(1,2)
True
>>> f(2,1)
False
```